# How can I run this command in vim

Tags: vim, command

I have the following command: `export TERM='xterm-256color'`. How can I run it in `vim`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a shell command, so you should put it in your shell profile e.g. ~/.bashrc (if you are using bash).

Alternatively, add `set t_Co=256` to your `~/.vimrc` or type `:set t_Co=256` when inside vim.

Answer (score 2):

That's a shell command for setting the terminal type.

You should run this in your Bourne-compatible shell *before* running `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it like:

```
:!export TERM='xterm-256color'
```

But you should set it before running `vim` (e.g. in your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc).